# (Beginner) Can't find the problem with this code in C, it returns weird values for the floats (-nanloat)

Tags: c, floating-point

It's just a super basic program that finds the roots of a quadratic function. After the calculations the output for the solutions shows "-nanloat" instead of the actual answer. Here's the problematic code:

```
    /*If the polynomial has real solutions, calculate and print them */
    if (nRSolutions > 0){
        sol = ((-b + sqrt(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a));
        printf("La solución a la ecuación es %float", sol);
        /*That means "the solution to the equation is (float)"*/
    }

    if (nRSolutions = 2){
        sol2 = ((-b - sqrt(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c)) / (2.0 * a));
        printf("La segunda solución a la ecuación es %float", sol2);
        /*That means "the second solution to the equation is (float)"*/
    }
```

Here's the variable declaration in case that might be part of the problem, but I really don't think that's it.

```
/* d = discriminant value; sol = solution; sol2 = second solution*/
float a, b, c, d, sol, sol2; 
    int nRSolutions;
    nRSolutions = 0;
```

They are all defined afterwards.

Comment: `%float` not needed, `%f` is enough. `loat` will be printed as-is confusing more.

Comment: What are the values of `a`, `b`, and `c`?  You might be trying to take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: An additional remark: It should be `if (nRSolutions == 2)`  instead of `if (nRSolutions = 2)`

Comment: When `(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c) < 0`, `sqrt(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c)` fails.

Comment: Thanks! @SouravGhosh I fixed that part. Turns out the faulty output is just "-nan". Still haven't fixed that though

Comment: Your variables are "all defined afterwards"?  Also nrSolutions == 0 so nothing happens.  `if (nrSolutions = 2)` assigns the value 2 to `nrSolutions`

Comment: <output for the solutions shows "-nanfloat"> --> Was it not really `"-nanloat"` without the `f`?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I already accounted for that previously in the code, it shouldn't execute that part if that's true. Still, I'm using values for which it should be positive though

Comment: @black nope, they're positive

Comment: @black sorry meant to answer someone else, thanks for that though, I keep fixing stuff with this, but the main problem persists

Comment: **What are they?** And are you sure you want to use `b^2+4ac` and not `b^2-4ac`?

Comment: @dbush They're positive

Comment: Post the input used and output expected, rather than only describing the input expected output.  A [mcve] is even better.

Comment: I don't think people downvoted because of the *code.* I think they downvoted because of the *question.*

Comment: afd2: Tip for future postings: Post a [mcve], inputs used, output seen and output expected.  Such questions favor up votes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
if (nRSolutions = 2){
```

You're not comparing but assigning, and since the value you're assigning is nonzero the condition will always be true.  You instead want:

```
if (nRSolutions == 2){
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong equation (in addition to issue identified by[@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64481632/2410359)).  See [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula):

```
// sqrt(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c))
sqrt(pow(b, 2.0) - 4 * a * c))
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^ ^
```

Even better as

```
double discriminate = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (discriminate < 0.0) TBD_code();
else sol = (-b + sqrt(discriminate)) / (2.0 * a);
```

---

Tip for improve precision: minimize subtraction cancellation

```
double discriminate = b*b - 4*a*c;
if (discriminate < 0.0) TBD_code();
// Add or subtract such that the result is larger
if (b < 0) sol = (-b + sqrt(discriminate)) / (2.0 * a);
else sol = (-b - sqrt(discriminate)) / (2.0 * a);

// We know a*sol*sol2 == c
sol2 = sol ? 0.0 : c/a/sol;
```

Comment: @Beta `sqrt(pow(2.0,b) + 4 * a * c)` can readily form a NaN result when the arg to `sqrt()` is less than 0.

Comment: Of course, but the OP says that the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are all positive (not that I'd bet my life on that).

Comment: Ah! Finally someone read my comment about the minus sign!

Comment: @Beta If OP used the correct `- 4 * a * c` rather than `+ 4 * a * c`, the arg to `sqrt()` can readily become negative.

Comment: ...But OP didn't use the correct formula. So this still doesn't solve the problem. (And it's not absolutely impossible that OP is using some screwy convention like `ax^2+bx=c`, in which case the `+4*a*c` is correct.)

Comment: Thanks!! That actually fixed it. Thank you so much. I kinda feel dumb now, I've been using this formula for years haha